# What is gzm (gizmo) and WGT

Tags: rigging

Everytime I import MXH2 to Blender, I find there are some meshes in the last layer. They are named "GZM....". What are they?
[image]

I find some WGT in a file from blendercloud. I don't understand what they are either. I fail to find some tutorials about them.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does abbreviations like DEF, MCH, CTRL, WGT stands for in rigging?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49076/what-does-abbreviations-like-def-mch-ctrl-wgt-stands-for-in-rigging)

Answer (score 1):

These are the shapes used for the custom bone shapes in the rig once the rig is generated. If you are in pose mode on a rig, you can go to the details of the bone in the property editor and see that you can reference a mesh object or empty as the new shape for the selected bone.

Comment: What if I delete them? Seem nothing happen... When I append one human model from another blend files. The GZM will be shown one by one in the Outline. :( They go out of the group or are appended automatically, which depends on how I import a model. @Craig