# INT prefix denotes bones which are used as Source in Copy Transform Constraint for DEF bones?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I understand that every rig and every studio is free to come up with and use prefixes as they please. But there are still common prefixes that most use the same.

If the INT prefix is widespread and is used in most cases the same - do I understand its meaning correctly?

INT prefix denotes bones which are used as Source in Copy Transform Constraint for DEF bones?

Comment: You are probably aware of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49081/42221)  -- it contains a list of the most common prefixes and their meaning and uses.  But in this case I have to ask if you have a typo in your question.  JNT is a common prefix but I've not seen INT used.  Did you definitely mean the I and not a J?

Comment: @MartyFouts I definitely mean "I"